# Java generics and wildcard - does not compile

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am unable to fix following code:

```
class Foo {
        private final Map<Class<? extends BaseAction>, Handler<? extends BaseAction>> map = new HashMap<>();
        {
            map.put(ActionA.class, new HandlerA());
            map.put(ActionB.class, new HandlerB());
        }

        void executeHandler(BaseAction command) {
            Handler<? extends BaseAction> handler = map.get(command.getClass());
            handler.handle(command); // fails..
        }

        abstract class BaseAction {}
        class ActionA extends BaseAction {};
        class ActionB extends BaseAction {};

        abstract class Handler<T extends BaseAction> {
            abstract void handle(T action);
        }

        class HandlerA extends Handler<ActionA> {
            @Override
            void handle(ActionA action) {}
        }

        class HandlerB extends Handler<ActionB> {
            @Override
            void handle(ActionB action) {}
        }
    }
```

The code does compile when handler map is in form:

`private final Map<Class<? extends BaseAction>, Handler> map = new HashMap<>();`

How to explain why more specific class type for map definition is not working?

Comment: Well `Handler` by itself is a raw type. What is the relationship you expect between `Class<? extends BaseAction>` and the raw `Handler`?